# Most efficient way to sort a leaderboard in SQL and update it in a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I might not have worded this right, but basically here is what I want to do:

- Display the leaderboard in a HTML table
- Each heading in the leaderboard is a link (e.g. score, time, kills)
- When each link is click it sorts the table depending what link is click (e.g. if kills is clicked it sorts the data showing the move kills at the top)

[Here](http://stuartjones.me/Staroids/leaderboard.php) is a link to my current leaderboard which works fine.

This is the code I have to far:

```
<div id="board">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="620"><tbody>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Score</td>             <---- WHEN CLICK = SORT IT BY SCORE
                <td>Wave Reached</td>      <---- WHEN CLICK = SORT IT BY WAVE
                <td>Seconds Survived</td>  <---- WHEN CLICK = SORT IT BY SECONDS
                <td>Kills</td>             <---- WHEN CLICK = SORT IT BY KILLS
                <td>Deaths</td>            <---- WHEN CLICK = SORT IT BY DEATHS
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php

                $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","localhost", "password");
                if (!$connect) {
                    die(mysql_error());
                }
                mysql_select_db("staroids");
                $results = mysql_query("SELECT name, score, wave, seconds, kills, deaths FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 10");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $score = $row['score'];
                $wave = $row['wave'];
                $seconds = $row['seconds'];
                $kills = $row['kills'];
                $deaths = $row['deaths'];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $name;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $score;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $wave;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $seconds;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $kills;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $deaths;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
                }
                mysql_close($connect);
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I hope this explains what I intend to do.

The code above displays the scores in descending order. Is there away to run a PHP script when a link is pressed in HTML like with JavaScript so it runs a specific query?

Comment: Check out https://datatables.net/. If you get all the data as JSON (sorting doesn't matter) from the server the Javascript will take care of the sorting.

Comment: Is there a way to do it server side in PHP? Client side could lead to potential security issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table header, you could link to the current page with a different parameter per link:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="currentpage.php?sort=name">Name</a></td>
    <td><a href="currentpage.php?sort=score">Score</a></td>           
    ...       
</tr>
```

then in php, you set the column you wanna sort depending of the value of the `$_GET["sort"]` parameter.
The value of `$sort` being the actual database column title.

```
if (isset($_GET["sort"])) {
    if ($_GET["sort"] == "name")
        $sort = "name";
    else if ($_GET["sort"] == "score")
        $sort = "score";
    else
        $sort = "score"; //default value
}
else
    $sort = "score"; //default value

$results = mysql_query("SELECT name, score, wave, seconds, kills, deaths FROM scores ORDER BY ".$sort." DESC LIMIT 10");
```

It's not the cleanest code, but it show the idea.
Good luck with this.

Comment: The problem is this selects the top 10 scores from the database which could have 100's of records... I think it needs to run a query for each header click then run the relevant SQL Select query.

Comment: Cheers! I was thinking something along those lines, I will give it a go now.

Comment: I have tried what you said, it outputs the following error: http://stuartjones.me/Staroids/currentpage.php?sort=wave
You can view the error [here] when you click on a header (http://stuartjones.me/Staroids/currentpage.php)

Comment: @smj2393 You should replace currentpage.php with the page you wish to use. I.e. leaderboard.php

Comment: Yea my bad I didn't mention that, I think just removing `currentpage.php` and putting `?sort=name` in the href would work too.